Move data partition (including its vss copies) to different disk in Windows Server 2019
What’s the best way to move a windows server 2019 (fileserver) data partition (including its vss copies) to another attached disk?
System and data are on same disk, but different partitions. I just need to move the data partition to another disk, but its existing shadow copies must not get lost (should also be moved).
